# Traveling to London with boyfriend, passport control together or separately

Tags: airports, london, customs-and-immigration

My boyfriend and I will be flying into London Gatwick and I'm wondering if we can go through passport control together, or if we have to approach separately?

I've seen a lot of information about families traveling together, but as we aren't family I'm not sure, especially with this airport

Comment: Do you live at the same address?

Comment: We do not live at the same address no

Comment: Do you and your boyfriend have the same citizenship?

Comment: Yes we are both from the USA

Comment: It's highly likely that you will be called up together/told to go together by the officers working the line.  When myself and my partner (different citizenships, and didn't live together at the time) travelled, we would always go together and there has never been an issue with that, even being told to stay together most of the time. Same has happened with myself and a group of friends (4 of us) so I think you will both be fine together. (Wrote here instead of answers as I have no sources)

Answer (score 3):

To expand on what DCClayworth said. One of the first questions you'll be asked is "Are you travelling with anyone else?" So answer "yes". It's very likely that the Officer will have seen you two interacting in the queue/line and will call you forward together.At Gatwick, I have very frequently heard the queue/line organisers say "If you are travelling together, go forward together". As DCClayworth pointed out, you can then corroborate each other's answers.

Answer (score 0):

The usual criterion for considering people to be family is If they live at the same address. Since you don't you should approach separately. Stick near each other so you can confirm each other's stories.